# Which camera is better for Arduino

Tags: arduino, camera

I  am looking for a CAMERA ( CMOS + Shield ) to implement on my Arduino project. I was using the LinkSprite JPEG but now is broken, I want to buy a new one but I am not sure that the LinkSprite is the better camera to use with Arduino.

The issue that I found on Linksprite was the slowness to download the picture and I couldn't to change the bitrate ( there is the command but didn't work ).

I found that there is the camera C328 that it was used for a lot of projects but now it's seems that is out of stock.

If you suggest me to rebuy the LinkSprite, do you have any example that I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

**[AVRcam](http://www.jrobot.net/Projects/AVRcam.html)** looks nice.

Comment: Yeah but I am looking something that the people know how to implement it on Arduino. The most supported camera for Arduino :)